# Grails filter data with dropdown

Tags: grails, filter

I want to add a data filter for my table. Can somebody help me?
I already have written a code for the list controller but I don't
know how to implement "mitarbeiterSelectedId" in my .gsp file.

At the moment I have the following code snippets.

This is my controller 'list'

```
def list(Integer max) {
    def mitarbeiterList = Mitarbeiter.listOrderByNachname()

    if (params.selectedMitarbeiterId != null && params.selectedMitarbeiterId != '-1'){
        mitarbeiterList = [Mitarbeiter.findById(params.selectedMitarbeiterId)]
    }
    [mitarbeiterInstanceList: mitarbeiterList, mitarbeiterInstanceTotal: Mitarbeiter.count() ]
}
```

This is my list.gsp

```
    <g:select id="mitarbeiter" name="mitarbeiterId" from="${Mitarbeiter.list()}" optionValue="nachname"
          optionKey="id"
          noSelection="${['-1': 'Bitte auswählen...']}" onchange="selectedMitarbeiterId"/>

<g:actionSubmit value="submit" onclick="" >OK</g:actionSubmit>


<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <g:sortableColumn property="nachname" params="[controller: 'mitarbeiter']"
                          title="${message(code: 'mitarbeiter.nachname.label', default: 'Nachname')}"/>

        <g:sortableColumn property="vorname" params="[controller: 'mitarbeiter']"
                          title="${message(code: 'mitarbeiter.vorname.label', default: 'Vorname')}"/>

        <g:sortableColumn property="sollpensum" params="[controller: 'mitarbeiter']"
                          title="${message(code: 'mitarbeiterHistory.sollpensum.label', default: 'Sollpensum')}"/>

        <sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN">

            <g:sortableColumn property="gehalt" params="[controller: 'mitarbeiter']"
                              title="${message(code: 'mitarbeiterHistory.gehalt.label', default: 'Gehalt')}"/>

        </sec:ifAllGranted>
        <th><g:message code="mitarbeiterHistory.bereich.label" default="Bereich"/></th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <g:each in="${Mitarbeiter.list()}" status="i" var="mitarbeiterInstance">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

            <td><g:link action="show" controller="mitarbeiter"
                        id="${mitarbeiterInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: mitarbeiterInstance, field: "nachname")}</g:link></td>

            <td>${fieldValue(bean: mitarbeiterInstance, field: "vorname")}</td>

            <td>${fieldValue(bean: mitarbeiterInstance.histories, field: "sollpensum")}</td>

            <sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN">
                <td>${fieldValue(bean: mitarbeiterInstance.histories, field: "gehalt")}</td>
            </sec:ifAllGranted>

            <td>${fieldValue(bean: mitarbeiterInstance.histories, field: "bereich")}</td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can somebody help my to fix this?

### EDIT :

Okay at the moment my class looks like this.

```
class Employee{

String firstname
String lastname

static hasMany = [histories:EmployeeHistory]


static constraints = {
    firstname nullable: false, blank: false, minSize: 2, matches: "[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜßéèáàúùóò'\\- ]+"
    lastname nullable: false, blank: false, minSize: 2, matches: "[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜßéèáàúùóò'\\- ]+"

}
}
```

so when I'm inserting your code it looks like this:

```
class Employee{

String firstname
String lastname

static hasMany = [histories:EmployeeHistory]


static constraints = {
    firstname nullable: false, blank: false, minSize: 2, matches: "[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜßéèáàúùóò'\\- ]+"
    lastname nullable: false, blank: false, minSize: 2, matches: "[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜßéèáàúùóò'\\- ]+"
}

static namedQueries = {
    filteronLastname { String inLastname ->
        if (inLastname && inLastname?.size() > 0) {
            ilike 'lastname', "%${inLastname}%"
        }
    }
}

}
```

If nothing is selected in dropdown I want to show the whole table data.
If I select a employee in dropdown I only want to show table with data of selected employee.

at the moment this is my list controller of employee

```
def list() {        
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
    def employeeList = Employee.filteronLastname(params?.lastName).list(params)
    [employeeInstanceList: employeeList, employeeInstanceTotal: employeeList.totalCount ]
}
```

where do I have to insert this:

```
NewsItem.filterLastname(params?.Lastname).
list()
```

and how I have to change the `<g:selected>`?

Comment: The '?.' is a Safe Navigation Operator, this is groovy syntax. So you can use the namedQuery like this: Employee.filteronLastname(params?.lastname).list(params) this will give you the employees with the filter applied. The use of '?.' will make sure that you will not get null-pointers if params.lastname is not filled and is null.

Comment: Sorry i did not get it. Can you please edit the code snippets?

Comment: I edited the code, but am not sure what you want with the dropdown box. In the example i assumed that you would have a g:textbox wich can contains part of the name of the employee you are searching.

could you paste you gsp code?

Comment: i want to have a dropdown box which displays the lastname of a employee. When i select a employee in the dropbox i want to update the table. I only want to show the selected employee. you know what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

To filter data we recently adopted another approach. To enable flexible filtering possibilities we have implemented filter methods using namedqueries.

A small example with some random code which explains the idea!:

```
class NewsItem {
    String title
    String message

    static namedQueries = {
        filteronTitleILike { String inTitle ->
            if (inTitle && inTitle?.size() > 0) {
                ilike 'title', "%${inTitle}%"
            }
        }

        filteronMessageILike { String inMessage ->
            if (inMessage && inMessage ?.size() > 0) {
                ilike 'message', "%${inMessage }%"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use the filtering we can now do something like this:

```
NewsItem.filterOnTitleILike(params?.title).
filterOnMessageILike(params?.message).
list()
```

A major advantage using this method is that we are very flexible when data is send from the gsp to the controllers. If params?.title is not filled aka null then this is not taken into account in the namedquery. So of we only feed the params?.message it keeps working perfect!

Comment: i have insert a edit section in my post. Can you please look at it.